# How to generate random 32bit integers in c++

Tags: c++, random

My understanding is that RAND_MAX is dependent on the architecture of the machine. If the machine is 32bit, than rand() will only generate something up to 4byte. How do I generate a 32bit random integer on a 64bit machine with rand()?

Also, do I always need srand() if I want to generate billions of random integers with rand() later?

Comment: just cast it off... `(uint32)rand()`

Comment: With c++11 there's a whole <random> header full of goodies: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random

Comment: You could probably just call rand twice, and combine the results into a single 32bit int, such as: (rand() ^ (rand() << 1)). But I don't know if this would give a descent distribution or not...

Comment: If you asked me for random numbers between 0 and 100, yet I gave you those between 0 and 200, wouldn't you just either (a) subtract 100 if the number was larger than 100, or (b) just use the units and tens digits (disregard the 100s digit, which could be 0, 1 or 2) - at the expense of a reduction by 1 in the range. i.e nums would be 0-99, rather than 0-100. Just AND the 64bit rand with 0xFFFFFFFF to ignore the portion of any num larger than 2^32. As for `srand` - _YES_ you do definitely need it, unless you want the sequence of 'random' numbers to be identical each time.

Comment: No. You said it yourself, `RAND_MAX` is dependent on the machine.

Comment: `RAND_MAX` depends on the _library implementation_, not the machine architecture, the only guarantee is that it's at least 32767. As far as I know in the GNU library it's 2147483647 and in Visual C++ it's 32767. I seriously suggest you look into the C++11 `<random>` library instead of `rand()`.

Comment: AND the 64bit rand with 0xFFFFFFFF is defintely a good idea. What if I do not know whether the OS is 64 of 32 and still want to generate a rand with N byte length (N<=4 or 8)?

Comment: @enhzflep, another though, AND the 64bit rand with 0xFFFFFFFF zeros the first 4byte, but it does not make the length of int half the size does it? I actually need to generate a random integer that has the length of 4 byte no matter what the OS is. How can it be done?

Comment: Correct, you still have a 64bit variable - it only has 32 bits of meaningful data (the remainder is 0). If you mask the lower 32 bits and then cast to a `uint32` as ASKASK says, you'll be fine. One exception is likely to be 16bit OS - I'd imagine (though forget) that the `rand()` function only returns 16 bits, in which case you'd have to glue the result of two calls to `rand` together. In hindsight, the masking seems irrelevant. I'd just go with ASKASK's suggestion.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since you are using rand() already, you probably don't have to worry about the period, so you can just mask the upper bits.

In general, you should do something like `srand(time(NULL))` once at the top of your program.  Otherwise, you will generate the same sequence of the billion random numbers every time you run the program.

Comment: RAND_MAX can be lower than you expect it to be.  It's not the same as MAX_INT.

You say "mask off the upper bits", but they're probably all zeros.  If you actually need 32bits of randomness, this is a bad answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using rand() with bit-hacking is seriously discouraged as it may lead to randomness issues in many cases.

The c++11 `<random>` header defines all the tools necessary for generating any kind of good quality random numbers, including integer of any length, floating point, etc...

I suggest watching this : https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful